# Idiomatic Scala: Semantic difference between <Collection>Like and <Collection> Types?

Tags: scala, naming, scala-collections

As title of this question suggests: my question is more about form (idiomatic convention) than function.  Put Succinctly:

> *What is the semantic difference between `MyCollectionLike` and `MyCollection`?*

As examples: What is the difference between `StringLike` and `String` or `MapLike` and `Map`.  Looking closely at the Scala API docs, I can tell that `XLike` is typically a super-type of `X`.  But, beyond that, I am not clear on the semantic difference between these layers of abstraction.

In practice, If I were creating a new class/trait, understanding this distinction would be helpful when I am choosing names for said class.

My specific problem, where this has come up is as follows:

> I want to create the trait: `SurjectiveMap[K, T]` which can be mixed-in with either `Map[K, Set[T]]` or `MapLike[K, SetLike[T]]`.  Given that I do not know the semantic difference between `*Like` and `*`, I am not sure which to go with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same difference as between IFoo and Foo, Bar and BarImpl (except the fact that TraversableLike is super-trait which contains implementation):

> The Scala collection library avoids code duplication and achieves the
>   "same-result-type" principle by using generic builders and traversals
>   over collections in so-called implementation traits. These traits are
>   named with a Like suffix; for instance, IndexedSeqLike is the
>   implementation trait for IndexedSeq, and similarly, TraversableLike is
>   the implementation trait for Traversable. Collection classes such as
>   Traversable or IndexedSeq inherit all their concrete method
>   implementations from these traits.

from [*Scala collections architecture*](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/scala_collections_architecture.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think using the `Like` traits lets you refine the return (representation) types. This involves a lot more work. Compare:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

object FooMap {
  type Coll = FooMap[_, _]
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A, B]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, (A, B), FooMap[A, B]] = ???
}
trait FooMap[A, +B] extends Map[A, B] {
  def foo = 33
}

def test(f: FooMap[Any, Any]) {
  f.map(identity).foo  // nope, we ended up with a regular `Map`
}
```

versus

```
object FooMap extends collection.generic.ImmutableMapFactory[FooMap] {
  override type Coll = FooMap[_, _]
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A, B]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, (A, B), FooMap[A, B]] = ???
  def empty[A, B]: FooMap[A, B] = ???
}
trait FooMap[A, +B] extends Map[A, B] 
  with collection.immutable.MapLike[A, B, FooMap[A, B]] {

  def foo = 33
  override def empty: FooMap[A, B] = FooMap.empty[A, B]
}

def test(f: FooMap[Any, Any]) {
  f.map(identity).foo  // yes
}
```

The `MapLike` trait must be mixed in after the `Map` trait for the correct return types to kick in.

---

Still you don't get everything for free it seems, e.g. you will need to override more methods:

```
override def +[B1 >: B](kv: (A, B1)): FooMap[A, B1]  // etc.
```